# c++ for every string in vector check if it contains a substring

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, substring

I need to write a program that gives the results of arithmetic operations for large positive integers. There are 4 basic operations to consider: addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*) and division of integers (/). The first line of the standard input contains a single integer Z  that determines the number of tests defined in the upcoming lines. Each test occupies one line of the standard input and contains a record of one arithmetic action, i.e., two strings of digits separated by an action operator (without additional spaces). The digit sequences are no more than 256 characters long. That's what I wrote to this moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Z;
    string operacja(256,'\0');
    cin >> Z;
    vector <string> operacje;
    for (int i = 0; i < Z; i++)
    {
            cin >> operacja;
            operacje.push_back(operacja);
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
    for(auto it = begin(operacje); it != end(operacje); ++it)
    {
        if (find_if(operacje.begin(), operacje.end(), [](const string& str) { return str.find("+") != std::string::npos; }) != operacje.end())
        {
            cout << "+" << endl;
        }
        else if (find_if(operacje.begin(), operacje.end(), [](const string& str) { return str.find("-") != std::string::npos; }) != operacje.end())
        {
            cout << "-" << endl;
        }
        else if (find_if(operacje.begin(), operacje.end(), [](const string& str) { return str.find("*") != std::string::npos; }) != operacje.end())
        {
            cout << "*" << endl;
        }
        else if (find_if(operacje.begin(), operacje.end(), [](const string& str) { return str.find("/") != std::string::npos; }) != operacje.end())
        {
            cout << "/" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

When I run the code I get this:

```
3
124/5
678-7
8/454545

-
-
-
```

I'm supposed to get this:

```
3
124/5
678-7
8/454545

/
-
/
```

Can somebody please help me fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> operacje;
    operacje.push_back("124/5");
    operacje.push_back("678-7");
    operacje.push_back("8/454545");

    for (const string& str: operacje)
    {        
        if (str.find("+") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "+" << endl;
        }
        else if (str.find("-") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "-" << endl;
        }
        else if (str.find("*") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "*" << endl;
        }
        else if (str.find("/") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "/" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just iterate through the strings in the vector and check for the wanted characters.  `find_if` is like a loop in itself and you weren't using the outer for loop at all. The result was that the operation was the same thing each time, as it started at the beginning of the vector every time.

Note this approach does have a fatal flaw, as `-` could be used to mean negative instead of subtract. So `5 * -3`. Would do the wrong thing.